# How do I write the Preorder Method for Binary Trees?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am having a very hard time understanding this. My homework assignment is as follows (**I input my homework assignment to let you fully understand my goal, not to have you do my homework assignment for me**):

Complete the implementation of the Linked Binary Tree class presented in this chapter. 
Specifically, complete the implementations of getRight, contains, isEmpty, toString, 
preorder, and post order operations.

I wrote all the methods that I knew how to write (though they are likely all wrong), but ------>**how do I write the preorder method?**<------ Here's my code so far (the preorder method section is at the bottom):
(**I have researched this** many times on **Google**, many times on **Stackoverflow**, and still **have not found an answer**. I did indeed go straight to my professor but I would also like a second opinion. He also has not responded yet. The main trouble here is finding people who use the code like I am supposed to, that is with iterator classes and node classes etc.)

```
    //*******************************************************************
    //  LinkedBinaryTree.java       Java Foundations
    //
    //  Implements a binary tree using a linked representation.
    //*******************************************************************

    package javafoundations;

    import java.util.Iterator;
    import javafoundations.*;
    import javafoundations.exceptions.*;

public class LinkedBinaryTree<T> implements BinaryTree<T>
{
   protected BTNode<T> root;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates an empty binary tree.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public LinkedBinaryTree()
   {
      root = null;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates a binary tree with the specified element as its root.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public LinkedBinaryTree (T element)
   {
      root = new BTNode<T>(element);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates a binary tree with the two specified subtrees.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public LinkedBinaryTree (T element, LinkedBinaryTree<T> left,
      LinkedBinaryTree<T> right)
   {
      root = new BTNode<T>(element);
      root.setLeft(left.root);
      root.setRight(right.root);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the element stored in the root of the tree. Throws an
   //  EmptyCollectionException if the tree is empty.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public T getRootElement()
   {
      if (root == null)
         throw new EmptyCollectionException ("Get root operation "
            + "failed. The tree is empty.");

      return root.getElement();
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the left subtree of the root of this tree.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public LinkedBinaryTree<T> getLeft()
   {
      if (root == null)
         throw new EmptyCollectionException ("Get left operation "
            + "failed. The tree is empty.");

      LinkedBinaryTree<T> result = new LinkedBinaryTree<T>();
      result.root = root.getLeft();

      return result;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the element in this binary tree that matches the
   //  specified target. Throws a ElementNotFoundException if the
   //  target is not found.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public T find (T target)
   {
      BTNode<T> node = null;

      if (root != null)
         node = root.find(target);

      if (node == null)
         throw new ElementNotFoundException("Find operation failed. "
            + "No such element in tree.");

      return node.getElement();
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the number of elements in this binary tree.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int size()
   {
      int result = 0;

      if (root != null)
         result = root.count();

      return result;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Populates and returns an iterator containing the elements in
   //  this binary tree using an inorder traversal.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Iterator<T> inorder()
   {
      ArrayIterator<T> iter = new ArrayIterator<T>();

      if (root != null)
         root.inorder (iter);

      return iter;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Populates and returns an iterator containing the elements in
   //  this binary tree using a levelorder traversal.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Iterator<T> levelorder()
   {
      LinkedQueue<BTNode<T>> queue = new LinkedQueue<BTNode<T>>();
      ArrayIterator<T> iter = new ArrayIterator<T>();

      if (root != null)
      {
         queue.enqueue(root);
         while (!queue.isEmpty())
         {
            BTNode<T> current = queue.dequeue();

            iter.add (current.getElement());

            if (current.getLeft() != null)
               queue.enqueue(current.getLeft());
            if (current.getRight() != null)
               queue.enqueue(current.getRight());
         }
      }

      return iter;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Satisfies the Iterable interface using an inorder traversal.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Iterator<T> iterator()
   {
      return inorder();
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  The following methods are left as programming projects.
   //----------------------------------------------------------------- 
   public LinkedBinaryTree<T> getRight() 
   { 
       if(root == null)
       {
           throw new EmptyCollectionException ("Get right operation "
                    + "failed. The tree is empty.");
       }
       LinkedBinaryTree<T> result = new LinkedBinaryTree<T>();
       result.root = root.getRight();

       return result;
   }  

   public Boolean Contains(T item) 
   {
       BTNode<T> result;
       result = root;
       if(root == null)
       {
           throw new EmptyCollectionException ("\'Contains\' operation "
                    + "failed. The tree is empty.");
       }
       if(root == item)
       {
           return true;
       }
       while(result.getElement() != item)
       {
           result = result.getRight();
       }
       while(result.getElement() != item)
       {
           result = result.getLeft();
       }
       if(root == null && result.getElement() != item)
       {
           return false;
       }
       return true;         
   }

   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
       if(root == null)
       {
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
       }
   }

   public String toString() 
   {
      return ("There are " + root.count() + " items in this tree.");

   }

   public Iterator<T> preorder() 
   {

   }


   // public Iterator<T> postorder() { }
}
```

And here are the links to the other classes if you need to see them:
[LinkedQueue](http://pastebin.com/PwYfMfEV)
[BTNode](http://pastebin.com/7U7UYh14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre order goes like this:

1. Visit the current node
2. If exists left node, visit pre order of left node.
3. If exist right node, visit pre order of right node.

I'm sure that with these few steps you will be able to implement your pre order method.

A pseudocode of this:

```
function preOrder(Node node)
    //1. visit current node
    show(node->data)
    //2. if exists left node, visit pre order of left node
    Node left = node->left
    if (left is not null)
        preOrder(left)
    //3. if exist right node, visit pre order of right node.
    Node right = node->left
    if (right is not null)
        preOrder(right)
```

Since this is homework, the implementation is up to you.

Comment: How is this not a real question? Ask: "Say something in order to obtain an answer or some information" -Google
Question: "A sentence worded or expressed so as to elicit information"
-Google

"but I'm struggling to write the preorder method." -Me.

Anyway, thank you for the response. I will work with it the best I can. I didn't just come in here to put my homework assignment in and have it done for me; I'm actually trying to learn.

Comment: @Brady since this is homework, the question looks like *I haven't tried anything, please do it for me* (at least in its current form where you haven't shown any effort to solve but just posted you have *problems* implementing it). That's why in my answer do not added any piece of code in order to solve the problem, instead an algorithm of how you can implement, possibly edit your question adding the results of your efforts (after having learned something) and asking what problem now you currently have.

Comment: I didn't want to write a boring paragraph stating "I have searched this in Google at least 10 times, I have searched StackOverflow at least 5 times, I have asked my professor and still struggle..."
Makes it sound like I am complaining. But next time I will make sure to do so. What you provided is good enough. I was about to ask how to mark my question "Answered," but I did some research and found it. Thanks Luiggi

Comment: @Brady it about **showing the code with your attempt** and then ask *I have this, now can you help me to find where's my error*? From your question, readers (like me and other 4 people) think that you tried nothing and want us to do your work (saying *I'm struggling with this* is not an option in this site).

Comment: As ludicrous as it may sound, I seriously had no idea of what to attempt. Sure, I could fill it with unreasonable code, but that would only confuse you and probably further make me look out-of-my-mind. Saying "I'm struggling with this" was to show that I'm not just here to fool around and type random stuff. I approached it like I would a professor, assuming that those who read it will become my own professors, since you are all very much smarter than I am. Trust me, I tried to do it myself but could not come up with 1 single thing.

Comment: @Brady you already did in order that is similar to pre order: 1. If there is a left node, visit left node in in-order. 2. visit current node, 3. If there is a right node, visit right node in in-order. There are some resembles between both methods, and I just wanted to show the base logic to do your own implementation.

Comment: I really do appreciate your help. I see now what you are saying as well. I also re-wrote my original question with much further clarification. Let me know if it's still incorrect and unworthy to be answered. You did mark it as not a question, but I appreciate that you went ahead and answered it anyway. I'm confused as to why you said it is not a question because you found the question and answered it. Regardless it is now clarified.

Comment: ` 
    public Iterator<T> preorder() 
   {
     ArrayIterator<T> iter = new ArrayIterator<T>();

     if (root != null)
        root.preorder (iter);

     return iter;
   }
    `

Comment: @Brady I can say that there is no specific way to implement a BST method, that's why on the net you will find different implementations. Remember that the main thing here is **understanding the algorithm**, if you're capable of that, the implementation will just flow out of your mind.

Comment: I am trying to write @LuiggiMendoza, "["At" sign here]Luiggi", etc, and it won't let me. I am also trying to implement code in here but the backticks are not working. I also tried moving it to chat but I don't have enough reputation. I also know the algorithm for it but was still lost. I must just be very slow with Java. I have it correct in my own code though, so we can close this thing officially or whatever. Sorry I was so slow to getting this thing right. Thanks again for the help. Maybe next time it will work better.